# Add new files & folders to WWW folder phone gap on XCODE

Tags: xcode, cordova

I created a new cordova project on XCODE, I have some files that I copied to the "www" folder by opening the www in finder then copying the files to it. 
The files are inside the www folder now but they don't appear on XCODE, So, do you know how can I make them appear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag and drop your www folder to your project in Xcode and choose 'create folder references for any added folders' from the popup and click 'Finish'.